# Show that $H_{1}\cap H_{2}$ is a normal subgroup of index 4 in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

This was given to us a few semester ago and would like to review on it (I did not get answers way back).

Given: group $G$ has two distinct subgroups $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ with $\left[G:H_{1}\right]=\left[G:H_{2}\right]=2$.

i. Show that $H_{1}\cap H_{2}$ is a normal subgroup of index 4 in $G$.

Proof. Since $\left[G:H_{1}\right]=\left[G:H_{2}\right]=2$, then $H_{1},H_{2} \trianglelefteq G$. Then, $H_{1}\cap H_{2}$ is normal in $G$. Moreover, $\left[G:H_{1}\cap H_{2}\right]\leq \left[G:H_{1}\right]\left[G:H_{2}\right]=4$. Since $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ are distinct subgroups, it follows that the order of $\frac{G}{H_{1}\cap H_{2}}$ cannot be 1, 2 or 3 and so $\left|\frac{G}{H_{1}\cap H_{2}}\right|=4$.

ii. To which known group is $\frac{G}{H_{1}\cap H_{2}}$ isomorphic?

iii. Explain why $G$ has a third subgroup $H_{3}$ with $\left[G:H_{3}\right]=2$.

iv. Express $H_{3}$ in terms of $G$, $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

ii. There are only two order-4 groups to consider. And seeing as $H_1/(H_1\cap H_2)$ and $H_2/(H_1\cap H_2)$ are both distinct, proper, non-trivial subgroups of $G/(H_1\cap H_2)$, that rules out one of the options.

iii. The group $G/(H_1\cap H_2)$ has three order-2 subgroups. We have accounted for two of them. So the third one must be $H_3/(H_1\cap H_2)$ for *some* subgroup $H_3\subseteq G$, by the third isomorphism theorem.

iv. The answer is
$$
H_3 = (H_1\cap H_2) \cup \big[(G\setminus H_1)\cap (G\setminus H_2)\big]
$$
It's not difficult to check that this subset contains the identity, and inverses of any elements, and that if it is a subgroup, it has index $2$. It is slightly more tricky to show that it is closed under multiplication, but using the fact that $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are both cyclic groups of order $2$ should help.

How to come up with this answer? It's what you get when you use the third isomorphism theorem for calculation rather than for proof of existence. So it's a natural consequence of iii.

Comment: Wow. Why does this things wont enter my mind? These are just amazing.

Comment: @FlickerBeat It's mostly practice. I've been doing elementary group theory for years (both on this site and at university). That makes many things come quickly and automatically. It doesn't mean I'm a great mathematician, but I am, at the very least, pretty decent at solving and explaining exercises.